# Browser window close and tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a JS function that detect only browser close and tab close functionality.
I used this code from http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/

I works for me but when i place a cursor on address and hit enter it goes to kill page method. I need only to show alert when tab or browser is closed.

Comment: You can't differentiate between the two. All your script will know is that the page is being unloaded. It doesn't know how.

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid this is not possible.

You cannot really make a distinction. When the user navigates away from your page in any way, you get the same events (`beforeunload`, `unload`). You can do some tricks (like in the link posted) whether the user clicked any of the links on your page or submitted one of your forms, but you cannot really differentiate between the refresh button, back button, the user entering a new address, the user clicking a bookmark, close tab, close browser, etc.

Comment: Hi,
I handled the refresh button, close window and tab. i want to handle entering enter on the same url on address bar. Then my work is done i dont want to handle back bookmark and other.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Anil Yes, I understand. It's not possible.